# How would I make this bookmarklet run on an interval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I have a great bookmarklet that reloads the css for the projects I'm working on. Right now I need to click the bookmark every time I want it to reload. What I want it to do is just set an interval.

This is it:

```
javascript:void(function(){var i,a,s;a=document.getElementsByTagName('link');for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){s=a[i];if(s.rel.toLowerCase().indexOf('stylesheet')>=0&&s.href) {var h=s.href.replace(/(&|%5C?)forceReload=\d+/,'');s.href=h+(h.indexOf('?')>=0?'&':'?')+'forceReload='+(new Date().valueOf())}}})();
```

This is what I tried:

```
javascript:void(

setInterval(
    function(){
        var i,a,s;
        a=document.getElementsByTagName('link');
        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            s=a[i];
            if(s.rel.toLowerCase().indexOf('stylesheet')>=0&&s.href) {
                var h=s.href.replace(/(&|%5C?)forceReload=\d+/,'');
                s.href=h+(h.indexOf('?')>=0?'&':'?')+'forceReload='+(new Date().valueOf())
            }
        }
    }, 500 
);

)();
```

Any ideas? I've never worked with bookmarklets.

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see the development version of your bookmarklet?

Comment: just curious why are you using `void()()` instead of `function()()`? What does that even do?

Comment: @float How doesn't it work? An error, or it doesn't call the interval? If you put some logging in there, can you see it appearing roughly ever 500ms ?

Comment: @alex Right it doesn't work at all in its current state.

Comment: @abdullah I didn't write the original bookmarklet. Just trying to quickly modifying the original, not sure why it's used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try to name the function then pass it to `setInterval`:

```
javascript: myfun = function() {...}; setInterval(myfun, 500);
```

Comment: using setInterval instead of setTimeout tho - thanks this works

Comment: Try to make it a unique name though so it doesn't collide with anything else.

Comment: this is great, btw. you guys should try it out if you work with css often.